# Finding limit and monotone in recursive function...

Tags: calculus, recursion

I have a recursive string

$\displaystyle C_1 = 10, \quad C_{n+1}=4-\frac{4}{C_n}, \quad n>0.$

How can I find the limit, $\lim_{ n\rightarrow\infty}C_n$ of this recursive function?

Also, would like to determine (with proof) whether or not this sequence is monotone.

${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: English is not my main language so i can't say it properply, sry. This is a row and i need to find if it is ascending or descending. And need to prove it...

Answer (score 0):

First by solving $l=4-{4\over l}$ we obtain $l=2$. Second, define $$e_n=C_n-2$$therefore $$e_{n+1}=2-{4\over e_n+2}={2e_n\over e_n+2}$$Note that $$e_2=1.6$$and$$e_n<2\implies e_{n+1}<e_n$$also we cannot have $e_n>\epsilon$ for all $n>3$ and some $\epsilon>0$ since this leads to$$|e_{n+1}|\le {2\over 2+\epsilon}|e_n|$$ which leads to a contradiction. Hence $|e_n|\to 0$ and $C_n\to 2$.